# Rewriting C# implementation of Snake class in F#

Tags: c#, performance, f#

This is my C# class, which takes 2.6s:

```
class Snake
{
    readonly Symbol _mySymbol;
    readonly int _multiplier;
    readonly int _hit;
    readonly int _payout;
    readonly Snake _bestSnake;

    public Symbol MySymbol { get { return _mySymbol; } }
    public int Multiplier { get { return _multiplier; } }
    public int Hit { get { return _hit; } }
    public int Payout { get { return _payout; } }

    public Snake BestSnake { get { return _bestSnake; } }

    public Snake(Apple myApple)
    {
        this._mySymbol = myApple.MySymbol;
        this._multiplier = myApple.Multiplier;
        this._hit = 1;
        this._payout = _mySymbol.Payout_[0] * (_multiplier == 0 ? 1 : _multiplier);
        this._bestSnake = this;
    }

    Snake(Symbol mySymbol, int multiplier, int hit)
    {
        this._mySymbol = mySymbol;
        this._multiplier = multiplier;
        this._hit = hit;
        this._payout = _mySymbol.Payout_[hit - 1] * (multiplier == 0 ? 1 : multiplier);
        this._bestSnake = this;
    }

    Snake(Symbol mySymbol, int multiplier, int hit, Snake bestRecentSnake)
        : this(mySymbol, multiplier, hit)
    {
        if (_payout < bestRecentSnake._payout)
        {
            this._bestSnake = bestRecentSnake;
        }
        else if (_payout == bestRecentSnake._payout)
        {
            if (bestRecentSnake._mySymbol.Type == 1 && mySymbol.Type != 1)
            {
                this._bestSnake = bestRecentSnake;
            }
        }
    }

    public Snake Eat(Apple nextApple)
    {
        var resultSymbol = Symbol.Add(_mySymbol, nextApple.MySymbol);
        if (resultSymbol == null)
            return null;

        var newSnake = new Snake(resultSymbol, Math.Max(_multiplier, nextApple.Multiplier), Hit + 1, _bestSnake);

        return newSnake;
    }
```

This is my F# class, which takes 5s:

```
type Snake (mySymbol: Symbol, multiplier, hit, best: Option<Snake>) =

let payout (mySymbol: Symbol) hit multiplier = 
    match multiplier with
    | 0 -> mySymbol.Payout_.[hit-1]
    | a -> mySymbol.Payout_.[hit-1] * a

new (myApple: Apple) = Snake (myApple.MySymbol, myApple.Multiplier, 1, None)

member this.BestSnake =
    match best with
    | Some a when this.Payout < a.Payout -> a
    | Some a when this.Payout = a.Payout && a.MySymbol.Type = 1 && mySymbol.Type <> 1 -> a
    | _ -> this

member this.MySymbol = mySymbol
member this.Payout = payout mySymbol hit multiplier
member this.Multiplier = multiplier
member this.Hit = hit

member this.Eat (myApple: Apple) =
    let tmp = Symbol.Add mySymbol myApple.MySymbol
    match tmp with
    | None -> Operators.Unchecked.defaultof<Snake>
    | Some a -> Snake (a, (max multiplier myApple.Multiplier), hit+1, Some this.BestSnake)
```

Comment: Could you also provide the code that you used to measure the performance? What exactly did you measure?

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but the whole point of using underscores before member variable names is so that you don't have to use `this.`. The underscore is a convention so that you always know what is a member variable instead of a method variable. It also allows you to never have to worry about a method variable shadowing a member variable.

Comment: On underscores: I strongly prefer `this.` over an underscore; so does Stylecop. I would also use auto-properties such as `public int Multiplier {get; private set;}` or have `readonly` fields (those can still be set inside of the constructor).

Comment: @svick sry it is too complicated if i attach the complete code. I measured the whole project which reference this class (before switch to F# is 2.6s vs after is 5s)

Comment: If you measured the whole project, how do you know this one class is the part that's slow?

Comment: One obvious difference I can see is that the F# version of the BestSnake property does work every time you call it, while the C# version simply returns a pre-calculated value every time you call it. Whether this matters or not to your performance measurement depends entirely on code that's not included here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few small differences in your translation. I would start with as literal a translation possible, then optimize/make idiomatic from there. If done incrementally it should be easy to spot performance problems as they occur. Here's a starting point:

```ml
(* stub *)
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type Symbol =
  member x.Payout = [|0|]
  member x.Type = 0
  static member Add(sym1, sym2) : Symbol = null

(* stub *)
type Apple =
  abstract MySymbol : Symbol
  abstract Multiplier : int

type private BestSnake =
  | This
  | RecentSnake of Snake

and [<AllowNullLiteral>] Snake private (mySymbol: Symbol, multiplier, hit, bestSnake) as this =
  let payout = mySymbol.Payout.[hit - 1] * (match multiplier with 0 -> 1 | m -> m)
  let bestSnake =
    match bestSnake with
    | This -> this
    | RecentSnake bestRecentSnake ->
      if payout < bestRecentSnake.Payout || 
        (payout = bestRecentSnake.Payout && bestRecentSnake.MySymbol.Type = 1 && mySymbol.Type <> 1) 
      then bestRecentSnake
      else null

  member val MySymbol : Symbol = mySymbol
  member val Multiplier = multiplier
  member val Hit = hit
  member val BestSnake = bestSnake
  member val Payout = payout

  new (mySymbol, multiplier, hit, bestRecentSnake) = Snake(mySymbol, multiplier, hit, RecentSnake bestRecentSnake)
  new (mySymbol, multiplier, hit) = Snake(mySymbol, multiplier, hit, This)
  new (myApple: Apple) = Snake(myApple.MySymbol, myApple.Multiplier, 1, This)

  member this.Eat(nextApple: Apple) =
    match Symbol.Add(this.MySymbol, nextApple.MySymbol) with
    | null -> null
    | resultSymbol -> Snake(resultSymbol, max this.Multiplier nextApple.Multiplier, this.Hit + 1, this.BestSnake)
```

The performance of this should be on par with C#.

Comment: I notice u used member val, is there any difference between to use/not to use val if the property is readonly of a default parameter? e.g. member val Hit = hit vs member Hit = hit

Comment: I used it because it guarantees (and therefore makes explicit) that the right-hand side is only evaluated once. If the right-hand side is a constant (as in this case) there is no difference.

Comment: new (myApple: Apple) as this = Snake(myApple.MySymbol, myApple.Multiplier, 1, this) at runtime raises {"The initialization of an object or value resulted in an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized."}

Comment: Oops—I didn't test it. It doesn't like passing `this` to another constructor. An alternate solution is to use a discriminated union to represent the different values that can be assigned to `bestSnake`. I've updated the code to demonstrate. I tested this time and it works.

Comment: thx, i have updated my question with latest improved F# code, still it is a bit slower than C#, I also attached some results from profiling tool. Even if I inline Symbol.Add, it would take 3 s which is longer than 2.6s

Comment: Hmm, your code doesn't even compile. Without your _complete_ source there's no way to help you further. I advise decompiling your F# and comparing it to the C# version.